# Reading and writing to file is non-blocking in my code. Why?

Tags: node.js, spotify, synchronous

I'm working on a bot used for Twitch Song Requests. The bot will read the Twitch chat, search for !sr command and get the name of the song. Then, it will search for the song in Spotify, get the URI of the song and add it in the streamer's playlist.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry if there are any "dumb" code problem (like the callback @ippi notified), I'm really new to programming and Node JS especially.

I now have two functions: one that is searching for the song and writing the received URI in a text file, and one getting the URI from the file. Here's the code:

**main code (call of the two functions):**

```js
testSong(commandName, accessToken);

let uri = getUri();

console.log(uri);
```

**search for the song:**

```js
function testSong(song, accessToken) {
    let song1;
    let song2;

    song1 = song.replace("!sr", "");
    song2 = song1.trim();

    var uri = "";

    axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(song2) + '&type=track&market=CH&limit=1', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    })
        // handle success
        .then(function (response) {
            uri = response.data.tracks.items[0].uri;
            console.log("yeet")
            fs.writeFileSync('conf/uri.txt');
            logger.log('info', 'Successfully obtained URI for track ' + song2);
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function (error) {
            logger.log('error', 'Error while accessing Spotify.');
            return error;
        });
}
```

**get the URI:**

```js
function getUri() {
    try {
        return fs.readFileSync('conf/uri.txt', 'utf-8');
    } catch (e) {
        logger.log('error', 'Error while reading the URI text file: ' + e.stack);
    }
}
```

---

I'm having a problem at the reading time. When running the bot for the first time, the uri.txt file is empty.

When I'm sending the first !sr in the Twitch chat, the song is not added in the Spotify playlist beacause it seems that the testSong command is writing to text file **AFTER** the getUri function read the file.

Even after that, I have to send a new !sr to add the first song, so every request is shifted.

Any idea why this is happening ?

I've read about async functions, but as far as I've understood, it's not what I want because I want the execution of the program to be blocked when I'm writing to the text file, thus the getUri function can then read the current requested song URI, and not be shifted.

---

**EDIT 2:** as Felix said, I modified the code as follow:

```js
testSong(commandName, accessToken).then(() => console.log(getUri()));
```

```js
function testSong(song, accessToken) {
    let song1;
    let song2;

    song1 = song.replace("!sr", "");
    song2 = song1.trim();

    var uri = "";

    return axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(song2) + '&type=track&market=CH&limit=1', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    })
        // handle success
        .then(function (response) {
            uri = response.data.tracks.items[0].uri;
            console.log("yeet")
            fs.writeFileSync('conf/uri.txt', uri, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                } else {
                    response = true;
                }
            });
            logger.log('info', 'Successfully obtained URI for track ' + song2);
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function (error) {
            logger.log('error', 'Error while accessing Spotify.');
            return error;
        });
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: First things first, `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])` does not accept a callback, only `writeFile` does. The callback is there to run in sometime in the future when writeFile completes.

Comment: You are writing it synchronously, but the write happens inside a function that is called asynchronously.  The "handle success" function won't be called until your current script (including `let uri = getUri()`) is done.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, but why? I've not specified that my testSong function has to be async. Are all functions asynchronous by default?

Comment: *"I've not specified that my testSong function has to be async"* You are using promises. The function you passed to `.then` will be called *some time in the future* when the promise was resolved. And that is guaranteed to take at least one iteration of the event loop. *"Are all functions asynchronous by default?"* No.

Comment: Ah!!! So I need to change it by using another API than Axios? Can you please tell me what to use if so?

Comment: No, you don't have to use another API. You just have to use promises correctly. The simplest solution would be to return the return value from `axios` (`return axios(...).then(...).catch(...)`) and then call the function as `testSong(commandName, accessToken).then(() => console.log(getURI()))`.

Comment: That said, of course you don't even have to write the URI to a file. `testSong` could just "return" the URI (return a promise that resolve to the URI).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and edit the code, then you can correct me if I did it wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, I was also thinking about just returning the URI. But how can I achieve this? Just add a return uri in the .then following the axios.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in my comments, you are having this problem because you are using promises, i.e. the file will be written some time in the future, *after* you are trying to read.

And as we discussed, there is no need to use a file to "transfer" the value at all. You can just return the value from `testSong` (wrapped in a promise):

```
function testSong(song, accessToken) {
    song = song.replace("!sr", "").trim();
    return axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(song2) + '&type=track&market=CH&limit=1', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    })
    // handle success
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data.tracks.items[0].uri;
    });
    // errors should probably be handled by the caller
}
```

and then:

```
testSong(commandName, accessToken)
  .then(function(uri) {
    console.log(uri);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
  });
```

---

An [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) makes working with promises a bit easier. So you could implement `testSong` also as

```
async function testSong(song, accessToken) {
    song = song.replace("!sr", "").trim();
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(song2) + '&type=track&market=CH&limit=1', {
    //               ^^^^^
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });
    return response.data.tracks.items[0].uri.
}
```